# Data Type Transformation Issue In R

Tags: r, vector, types

When a vector `a` is transformed to a `factor` and transformed back to `numeric`, why does `a` prints out different elements?

```
a = c(9, 10, 11, 12)
a = as.factor(a)
a
> a
[1] 9  10 11 12
Levels: 9 10 11 12

a = as.numeric(a)
a
> a
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: You need `as.numeric(as.character(a))` or  `as.numeric(levels(a)[a])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the values showed by direction conversion is the integer storage values.  We need to either convert it to `character` and then to `numeric`

```
a1 <- as.numeric(as.character(a))
```

Or use a faster option with `levels`

```
a1 <- as.numeric(levels(a)[a])
a1
#[1]  9 10 11 12
class(a1)
#[1] "numeric"
```